# 2D array where the bigger array is dynamic and the smaller arrays are not

Tags: c

In C, if I don't know the number of rows at compile time, but I do know the number of columns, how do I initialize the array?

If I want a non-dynamically allocated array, I type `int 2D_array[128][128];` but if I want a dynamically allocated array, I type

```
int** 2D_array = (int**)calloc(num_rows, sizeof(int*));
for (int i = 0; i < num_rows); i++) {
   2D_array[i] = (int*)calloc(num_columns, sizeof(int));
}
```

But what if I want to have a 2D array where the rows are dynamic, but the columns are not? My intuition is `int* 2D_array[128];` but that would just give me a 2D array with 128 rows and dynamically allocated columns.

Comment: Identifiers can’t begin with digits.

Answer (score 1):

You can allocate the entire thing at once. A `typedef` makes it easier to specify the array declaration.

```
typedef int[128] row;
row *twoD_array = calloc(num_rows, sizeof(row));
```

Comment: What's the difference between ```int[128] row;``` and ```int row[128];```?

Comment: It's a `typedef`, it's defining `row` as an alias for `int[128]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you are trying to access  2D_array[row][column]. You can access any column value only through after de referencing the row address .So, if we change as 2D_array[column][row],it is possible. But we need to change array's value accessing logic in remaining application.